# What is the fastest format for a key in a JS object [Improved]

Tags: javascript

## Backround Info

For a program I'm working on I need to track the path taken through a web. In this case, a web is defined a series of nodes, each node having zero or more child nodes. It's a web and not a tree because any node can point to any other and can be circular.

My program will start at one "entry point" node, and traverse through the web until it has taken a path that is considered "valid". All valid paths are stored in a series of nested maps, each map containing the keys of all possible next steps.

For example:

```js
{ 0: {1: "success"} }
```

This nested map defines the path:

```
entryNode.children[0].children[1]
```

I have a minimal example of the traversal algorithm for benchmarking purposes:

```js
// you can ignore this, it just helps me get some more info on the results
function getStandardDeviation (array) {
    const n = array.length
    const mean = array.reduce((a, b) => a + b) / n
    return Math.sqrt(array.map(x => Math.pow(x - mean, 2)).reduce((a, b) => a + b) / n)
}

//// values that can be converted to a 1-digit base-36 number
// let list = [30, 31, 32]
//// without base-36: 411ms
//// with base-36: 2009ms

//// values that can be converted to a 2-digit base-36 number
// let list = [36, 37, 38]
//// without base-36: 391ms
//// with base-36: 1211ms

//// arbitrary large numbers
let list = [10000, 10001, 10002]
//// without base-36: 4764ms
//// with base-36: 1954ms

//// I tried encoding to base 36 to reduce the key length, hence the keys like '1o' and '1p'
//// This seems to hurt the performance of short numbers, but help the performance of large ones
// list = list.map(n => n.toString(36))

let maps = {}
let currentMap = maps
list.forEach((n, i) => {
    if (i === list.length - 1) {
        currentMap[n] = "res1"
    } else {
        const tempMap = {}
        currentMap[n] = tempMap
        currentMap = tempMap
    }
})
console.log(maps)

// store samples for stdev
let times = []

const samples = 1000
const operations = 100000

// collect samples for stdev calculation
for (let k = 0; k < samples; k++) {
    const begin = process.hrtime()
    // dummy variable to simulate doing something with the result
    let c = ""
    let current = maps
    for (let i = 0; i < operations; i++) {
        // simulate what the final algorithm does
        for (let j = 0; j < list.length; j++) {
            current = current[list[j]]
            if (typeof current === 'string') {
                c = current
            }
        }
        current = maps
    }
    const end = process.hrtime()
    // get the ms difference between start and end
    times.push((end[0] * 1000 + end[1] / 1000000) - (begin[0] * 1000 + begin[1] / 1000000));
}

const stdev = getStandardDeviation(times)
let total = 0;
times.forEach(t => total += t)

console.log("Time in millisecond is: ", total.toFixed(2), `+-${stdev.toFixed(2)}ms (${(total - stdev).toFixed(2)}, ${(total + stdev).toFixed(2)})`)
```

## The Question

While testing, I wondered if using shorter keys would be faster, since I'm guessing JS hashes them somehow before doing the lookup. And I found that different object keys resulted in drastically different performance, varying by about an order of magnitude, with the only difference being the size/characters used in map's keys. There's not an obvious pattern that I can see, though.

I laid out the different input lists and their results in the top of the benchmark source, but here's the actual maps used and their respective times:

```
// raw numbers
{ '30': { '31': { '32': 'res1' } } }
Time in millisecond is:  411.00 +-0.13ms (410.86, 411.13)

// converted to base-36
{ u: { v: { w: 'res1' } } }
Time in millisecond is:  2009.91 +-0.18ms (2009.72, 2010.09)

// raw numbers
{ '36': { '37': { '38': 'res1' } } }
Time in millisecond is:  391.52 +-0.16ms (391.36, 391.69)

// converted to base-36
{ '10': { '11': { '12': 'res1' } } }
Time in millisecond is:  1211.46 +-0.19ms (1211.27, 1211.65)

// raw numbers
{ '10000': { '10001': { '10002': 'res1' } } }
Time in millisecond is:  4764.09 +-0.17ms (4763.93, 4764.26)

// converted to base-36
{ '7ps': { '7pt': { '7pu': 'res1' } } }
Time in millisecond is:  1954.07 +-0.17ms (1953.90, 1954.25)
```

### Why do these differeny keys result in such wildly different timings? I've tested it a lot and they are quite consistent

*Note:
I'm using Node V16.15.0 for benchmarking*

Comment: just for the info, what processor are u packing in this test?

Comment: I ran this on an M1 but I’ll eventually run it on my main 3900x

Comment: I remember someone asking how the javascript object works and someone said that they don't use hashmaps I believe.. on that note I could imagine breaking up the key into values in a link list of arrays `eg 'l' is ascii 108 and if it's arrays of 10, it'd be 1->0->8`

Comment: while I am merely spitballing I describe what I mean [here](https://github.com/0utPost/object) and in this weird way of doing things some keys will take longer to reach than others.. however for 10 to be accessed slower than 36 maybe they don't break the numbers off of ascii and some special alphabet with the most likely characters first?

Comment: That would explain the inconsistency. I’ll see if I can do a mass test of different keys and sort them by performance